# Events when dock is showing or hiding

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, dock

How can I get events when the Dock is showing or hiding?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a notification if the dock is visible or not using Carbon. I do not know of any way to do it in Cocoa.

(I haven't tested this; it's from the code [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/210267-could-keventappsystemuimodechanged-arrive-too-early-to-my-handler.html))

Create your callback method:

```
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

static const EventTypeSpec appEvents[] = {
    { kEventClassApplication, kEventAppSystemUIModeChanged }
};

OSStatus DockChangedHandler(EventHandlerCallRef inCallRef, EventRef event, void *userData) {
    OSStatus status = eventNotHandledErr;
    switch(GetEventClass(event)) {
        case kEventClassApplication: {
            SystemUIMode *outMode;
            SystemUIOptions *outOptions;
            GetSystemUIMode(outMode, outOptions);
            status = noErr;
        }
            break;

        default: 
            return;

    }

    /*Insert whatever you want to do when you're notified of a dock change*/

    return status;
}
```

And then put this wherever you want to start listening for the notification:

```
    InstallApplicationEventHandler(NewEventHandlerUPP(DockChangedHandler), GetEventTypeCount(appEvents), appEvents, 0, NULL);
```

Further information: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2002/tn2062.html